# SUMX, SUMMARIZE, and missing values

Tags: excel, dax

I have a somewhat complicated scenario that I'm trying to build out in Excel using PowerPivot. We have sales pipeline items that each represent a sales opportunity and, associated with each of those pipelines, a number of events. I have history tables for both pipelines and events and would like to use them to construct a model of how a given sales executive's entire pipeline set has changed over time.

The result set from my SQL query might look like this:

| pipeline_id | date_last_mod | pipeline_event_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P-01 | 1/1/2020 | PE-01 | 100 |
| P-02 | 1/1/2020 | PE-02 | 500 |
| P-02 | 1/2/2020 |  |  |
| P-02 | 1/2/2020 | PE-02 | 1000 |
| P-03 | 1/1/2020 | PE-03 | 200 |
| P-03 | 3/1/2020 | PE-03 | 200 |
| P-03 | 4/1/2020 | PE-04 | 300 |
| P-03 | 5/1/2020 | PE-03 | 400 |
| P-03 | 5/15/2020 | PE-03 | 300 |

I also have a date table with the usual fields. What I'm trying to produce is a PivotTable that looks like the following. You can see it takes the most recent 'amount' value of each pipeline event and sums those up as of the end of each month.

| Year | Month | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 800 |
| 2020 | 2 | 800 |
| 2020 | 3 | 800 |
| 2020 | 4 | 1100 |
| 2020 | 5 | 1200 |

It seems like the solution should be something with SUMX and LASTNONBLANK. I have a measure that looks like this:

```
TestRev:=VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod] )
        RETURN
SUMX( ADDCOLUMNS( SUMMARIZE( qryPipelineUS, qryPipelineUS[pipeline_id], qryPipelineUS[pipeline_event_id] ), "temp",
CALCULATE (
                SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ),
    LASTNONBLANK( qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod], CALCULATE( SUM( qryPipelineUS[amount] ) ) ),
                ALL( qryDateTable ),
                ALLEXCEPT( qryPipelineUS, qryPipelineUS[pipeline_event_id] ),
                qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod] <= MaxDate ) ), [temp] )
```

The problem with it seems to be that the SUMMARIZE function won't generate rows for pipeline_event_id's in months that don't have entries for them. Makes sense, really. Even when I try to do something with CROSSJOIN, I can generate a table with the ID's I need, but can't get it to generate data.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions as to how I should go about this. I've been beating my head against the problem for a couple weeks now and I'm not getting anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to do your date calculations on the date table rather than your fact table and to remove date filters on your SUMMARIZE table.

Here's how I'd adjust your measure:

```
TestRev =
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( qryDateTable[Date] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    qryPipelineUS,
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_id],
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_event_id]
                ),
                ALL ( qryDateTable )
            ),
            "temp",
                CALCULATE (
                    LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
                        qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod],
                        CALCULATE ( SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ) )
                    ),
                    qryDateTable[Date] <= MaxDate
                )
        ),
        [temp]
    )
```

**Edit:** In Excel, LASTNONBLANKVALUE is not recognized so you can use this expanded version:

```
Test =
VAR MaxDate = MAX ( qryDateTable[Date] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    qryPipelineUS,
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_id],
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_event_id]
                ),
                ALL ( qryDateTable )
            ),
            "temp",
                CALCULATE (
                    CALCULATE (
                        SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ),
                        LASTNONBLANK (
                            qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod],
                            CALCULATE ( SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ) )
                        )
                    ),
                    qryDateTable[Date] <= MaxDate
                )
        ),
        [temp]
    )
```

Note that the date filter is ***not*** included in the same internal CALCULATE expression as LASTNONBLANK. If you did that, the measure would not work the same way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This certainly seems like it should do the trick, but it's still missing some data. Maybe I'm not providing a complete enough example to capture all the intricacies here. What seems to happen is that if there is a record for a particular month, it will capture that data correctly. However, if an event is created in January, nothing changes in February (hence no record), and then changes again in March, it will pick it up for Jan and Mar, but not Feb. Any thoughts on how to work around that?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your table since I couldn't figure out where e.g. 800 was coming from in the first few rows but I did get results for each month when I tried. Perhaps you can post clarified sample data and desired result?

Comment: Here's a file with some affected actual data and the resulting filtered PivotTable. The desired outcome is that rows for Feb also exist with the same data as Jan.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kvlhjtgw38da0g5l9je3w/sample_data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=1r33o4a7olnn08c26hdhapign

Comment: By the way, I presume it makes no difference since it's just syntax sugar, but I had to use CALCULATE( expression, LASTNONBLANK( column, CALCULATE( expression ) ) ), since Excel hasn't implemented LASTNONBLANKVALUE yet.

Comment: You need to be careful with the conversion and not try to include it in the same CALCULATE as the date filter. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, so much! That did the trick. I've got a couple other tweaks to add to make it perfectly match the data I'm looking for, but this was the core of it. That was a subtle change that I don't think I'd have picked up on.

Comment: Alexis - I have a further problem that has cropped up with this and was hoping you could assist, if it's not too much trouble. I don't think it will be difficult, but I just have trouble wrapping my head around how some of these advanced concepts work. How do you suggest I proceed? Thank you -- volfied

Comment: I suggest you write a new question post. I can’t guarantee I’ll answer it but I’ll at look at it if I see it.

Comment: Thanks, Alexis. Here's the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505937/further-partitioning-an-already-complex-calculation