# Further Partitioning an Already Complex Calculation

Tags: excel, dax

Piggy-backing on my earlier question here: [SUMX, SUMMARIZE, and missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270408/sumx-summarize-and-missing-values/67271068)

I have a new wrinkle that I can't quite work out. I would have thought it was simple or wouldn't even be a problem, but here I am.

Alexis worked out this solution for me that calculates the final amount for each pipeline_event and sums it up for an accurate grand total. What I need to do now is show all that aggregated data split up by the final probability value for that given period of time. The problem is that the same data is showing up in multiple places on the more granular level, even though the grand total is still correct. Let me back up a bit...

We have pipeline_history records and pipeline_event_history records. I've written a SQL query that pulls them into a single row for each matching pair. Each row contains an 'amount' and an 'eveprob'. The latter is a number from the set `{0,10,30,50,70,90,100}` that reflects the probability that the particular event will close successfully. The values are in a linked table named tblProb[Prob]. Over the course of time, both these values may change, so I may have a result set for a particular event that looks like this:

| pipeline_id | date_last_mod | pipeline_event_id | amount | eveprob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P-03 | 1/1/2020 | PE-04 | 200 | 10 |
| P-03 | 3/1/2020 | PE-04 | 200 | 30 |
| P-03 | 5/1/2020 | PE-04 | 200 | 30 |
| P-03 | 5/15/2020 | PE-04 | 400 | 50 |

What my PivotTable is giving me is this:

| Year/Month | 0 | 10 | 30 | 50 | 70 | 90 | 100 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2020 |  | 200 |  |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| Feb 2020 |  | 200 |  |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| Mar 2020 |  | 200 | 200 |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| Apr 2020 |  | 200 | 200 |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| May 2020 |  | 200 | 400 | 400 |  |  |  | 400 |

What I'm after is this:

| Year/Month | 0 | 10 | 30 | 50 | 70 | 90 | 100 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2020 |  | 200 |  |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| Feb 2020 |  | 200 |  |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| Mar 2020 |  |  | 200 |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| Apr 2020 |  |  | 200 |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| May 2020 |  |  |  | 400 |  |  |  | 400 |

Here's my measure as it stands now:

```
Revenue:=
VAR MaxDate = MAX ( qryDateTable[Date] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    qryPipelineUS,
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_id],
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_event_id]
                ),
                ALL ( qryDateTable )
            ),
            "temp",
                CALCULATE (
                    CALCULATE (
                        SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ),
                        LASTNONBLANK (
                            qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod],
                            CALCULATE ( SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ) )
                        )
                    ),
                    qryDateTable[Date] <= MaxDate
                )
        ),
        [temp]
    )
```

I've tried adding tblProb[Prob] to the SUMMARIZE and/or tweaking the CALCULATE(s) to match the Prob value in the filter context, but I'm either doing it wrong or it's the wrong approach. I'd owe you a big one if you could help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution with some redundancies stripped out:

```
Revenue := 
VAR MaxDate = MAX ( tblDates[Date] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    qryPipelineUS,
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_id],
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_event_id]
                ),
                ALL ( tblDates )
            ),
            "temp",
                CALCULATE (
                    VAR LastProb =
                        CALCULATE (
                            CALCULATE (
                                MAX ( qryPipelineUS[eveProb] ),
                                LASTNONBLANK (
                                    qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod],
                                    CALCULATE ( SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ) )
                                ),
                                ALL ( tblDates )
                            ),
                            ALL ( tblProb )
                        )
                    RETURN
                        CALCULATE (
                            SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ),
                            LASTNONBLANK (
                                qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod],
                                CALCULATE ( SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ) )
                            ),
                            tblProb[Prob] = LastProb
                        ),
                    tblDates[Date] <= MaxDate
                )
        ),
        [temp]
    )
```

(Posted as a solution since it doesn't work as a comment.)

Comment: Thank you, Alexis. That's certainly cleaner than my version. This whole report is humming along smoothly now.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Here's the final version:

```
Revenue :=
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( tblDates[Date] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                SUMMARIZE (
                    qryPipelineUS,
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_id],
                    qryPipelineUS[pipeline_event_id]
                ),
                ALL ( tblDates )
            ),
            "temp",
                CALCULATE (
                    VAR LastProb =
                        CALCULATE (
                            CALCULATE (
                                CALCULATE (
                                    CALCULATE (
                                        MAX ( qryPipelineUS[eveProb] ),
                                        LASTNONBLANK (
                                            qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod],
                                            CALCULATE ( SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ) )
                                        ),
                                        ALL ( tblDates ),
                                        tblDates[Date] <= MaxDate
                                    )
                                ),
                                ALL ( tblProb )
                            ),
                            ALL ( tblDates ),
                            tblDates[Date] <= MaxDate
                        )
                    RETURN
                        CALCULATE (
                            SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ),
                            LASTNONBLANK (
                                qryPipelineUS[date_last_mod],
                                CALCULATE ( SUM ( qryPipelineUS[amount] ) )
                            ),
                            tblProb[Prob] = LastProb
                        ),
                    tblDates[Date] <= MaxDate
                )
        ),
        [temp]
    )
```

The trick was calculating the LastProb variable in the right way and in the right place. I tried calculating it up top at first, but that didn't work for aggregations, because it needed to calculate a different value for each event. I was surprised it needed so many nested CALCULATEs, but I kept trying to pare it back and it didn't work that way. Please do chime in if you have any insights.